# How can I make a Vehicle as a Device?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e, vehicles

I'm designing a character that wears a power suit, but that also has a second, larger power suit that he uses for long distance travel & hazardous environments.  The issue is that the second suit is large enough that multiple (two other) people can fit inside.

These two passengers benefit from the increased movement speed, defences, and life support, but are otherwise unable to participate in combat or anything else while passengers. This is an alt of the main suit Device power, not a vehicle, but it mainly acts as a vehicle (mostly).

How would you go about building this?

Fluff-wise, the character summons the second suit/vehicle, and his main suit integrates with the second one enabling him to control it (sort of like the Iron Man 'Veronica' suit.)

Comment: Welcome to the stack Arlyansor, take the [tour] when you have a moment, and review the [help] articles for more info about the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Build it as a vehicle, as an alternative of the main power armor device.

Simply put, if the power armor is worth X points, then they can spend a point to buy Alternate Effect (Flying Suit), which consists of X levels of the Improved Advantage (Equipment) trait, which provides Equipment Points that can be used to build a Vehicle.

Comment: That's an innovative, out-of-the-box solution, and one that would normally work, buuuttt...  we use the HeroLab software for character creation & maintenance, and it simply won't do that.  At all.  Don't get me wrong, I like the idea and the elegant simplicity of it, I just can't do it with this character and group.

Comment: You can still add the vehicle as a "free" item and then add a Feature coding the right amount for the Equipment points.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions, they were all very interesting.
In the end, the primary issue I was facing was due to the shortfalls of HeroLab just not being equipped to handle this concept.
In the end, I opted for the following:
An Alternate to the primary power suit with which I purchased the necessary ranks of Feature: Placeholder for Vehicle Cost
I then designed the vehicle as needed, and marked that the entire cost had been met as 'Shared EP from other Heroes.'
This zeroed the cost to the Primary character, leaving only the 1 PP  cost for the Alternate Power.
It's a kludge, but that's a limitation in HeroLab.  Mechanically, the maths sort-of adds up.
So, thanks again for the answers, especially nick012000 and Sean Duggan.

Comment: I kind of get that this is your self-answer (which can be accepted by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]), but it's also kind of a comment on existing answers, so you're probably going to get flagged.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to update with the solution you chose. That is valuable information for future readers. However your post reads more like a "thankyou" than an answer, which are generally discouraged. If an answer helped you the best way to show that is to upvote or accept as answer. I suggest you edit your post to remove the thankyou parts and focus on how you solved the problem instead.

Comment: This is an honest attempt at answering the question with the chosen solution — that is also thanks and acknowledges the inspiration for the solution doesn't turn it into a mere "Thank you." Instead it would be useful to add how that played out at your table, so that future querents with the same problems may draw their conclusions. [—From Review](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/78427)

Answer (score 0):

The *Vehicles Power Profile* suggests, under the section for vehicle life support, to use Affects Others to account for additional passengers. Personally, since vehicles don't tend to add all that much to the passengers, basically just providing Speed and Cover (with some fairly severe limitations in that said Speed can only be used in a single destination), I generally just use the 2E Progression Feats ("Flat Extras" in 3E) so 1 PP to allow 1 additional passenger, 2 PP for 2, 3 PP for 5, etc.